# Pandas : Groupby sum values

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am using this data frame in excel :

I'd like to show the total sales per year.

```
Year    Sales
2021    7
2018    6
2018    787
2018    935
2018    1 059
2018    5
2018    72
2018    2
2018    3
2019    218
2019    256
2020    2
2018    4
2021    8
2019    14
2020    3
2018    3
2018    1
2020    34
```

I'm using this :
 `df.groupby(['Year'])['Sales'].agg('sum')`

And the result :

```
2018.0    67879351 05957223431
2019.0                21825614
2020.0                    2334
2021.0                      78
Do you know why I don't have the sum of the values ?
Thanks
```

Comment: Look at the value `1 059`, it has white space character so it's a string not a number.

Comment: Thanks, i modified and it's works now !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Sales' column is of dtype object so convert it to numeric:

```
df['Sales']=pd.to_numeric(df['Sales'].replace(r"\s+",'',regex=True),errors='coerce')
#df['Sales'].replace(r"\s+",'',regex=True).astype(float)
```

Now calculte `sum()`:

```
out=df.groupby(['Year'])['Sales'].sum()
```

output of `out`:

```
Year
2018    2877
2019     488
2020      39
2021      15
Name: Sales, dtype: int64
```